# Error: Package: ImageMagick-6.9.11.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)

Tags: imagemagick, cpanel, whm, epel

I'm getting following error for cPanel command.

Not sure how to resolve this issue. Any help?

Full log https://pastebin.com/PRuYP6tg

#/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rpmup

...

```
Error: Package: ImageMagick-6.9.11.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
Error: Package: ImageMagick-libs-6.9.11.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
info [rpmup] Completed yum execution “--assumeyes --color=never --config /etc/yum.conf update --disablerepo=epel”: in 3.459 second(s).
(XID dx5fnu) “/usr/bin/yum” reported error code “1” when it ended:
checkyum version 22.3  (excludes: bind-chroot ruby)

# yum repolist all | grep epel
 * epel: ewr.edge.kernel.org
epel/x86_64                          Extra Packages for Ente enabled: 12,624+802
epel-debuginfo/x86_64                Extra Packages for Ente disabled
epel-source/x86_64                   Extra Packages for Ente disabled
epel-testing/x86_64                  Extra Packages for Ente disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64        Extra Packages for Ente disabled
epel-testing-source/x86_64           Extra Packages for Ente disabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EPEL repository is missing, which provides missing dependencies.

Explained in the repository [configuration page](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/Config-en) and in the [FAQ](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#deps)

Comment: It is already installed. 
(1/2): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                          | 1.0 MB  00:00:00     
(2/2): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                          | 6.9 MB  00:00:00     
Package epel-release-7-12.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: But not enabled, as it is not listed in your paste, and it provides needed libraqm

Comment: I've checked and it seems to be enabled. If not how do I enable it?

Comment: enabled=1 in the config file ? or see yum-config-manager command ?

Comment: I seem to have fixed it somehow. Not sure how I did. Probably yum update or something. Thanks for help and pointing out that this issue was related with epel. I wouldn't have known it otherwise.